# My Autorization token and header not being passed to my request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

All i have the following setup
[image: In this image i am creating a request to get the token]

I am able to get the token
[image: Get token]

Some Request to an API endpoint
[image: Sending Request]

The Header:
[image]

Beanshell
[image]

When i view my results, i am seeing that my request is failing:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare</center>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

It looks like i can seem to set my content type correctly
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: cloudflare
Date: Sat, 21 Oct 2023 21:51:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 155
Connection: close
CF-RAY: -

In my postman it works fine and the header should be application/xml and i put that in the header.... what am i doing wrong here?
I eventually want to pick up messages from the MQ webshere and then send that message in the body to the api endpoint and would need some advice on that..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need the Beanshell PreProcessor, [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) will add the token.
2. You don't need to send `Connection` header, you already have `Use Keep/Alive` box ticked in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

Maybe your JSON Extractor configuration is wrong, move the Debug Sampler to be **after** the `Http URLAPI Test` and take a look at `auth_token` variable value. See [How to Debug JMeter Test Scripts](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) for more details.

In general given you can successfully execute the request in Postman you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and after [correlating](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) the dynamic parameters it should start working in JMeter as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some time, i was able to resolve this issue

Here my New structure:
[image]

Create a Once only controller call it Initialize token
i had a jsr223 post processor that stores the token time

a) get the token
[image]
${__time(,tokenGenerationTime)}
String tokenGenerationTime =
String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
vars.put("tokenGenerationTime", tokenGenerationTime);
log.info("Token Generation Time: " + tokenGenerationTime);

i then call the get claim and store the value in a variable with a jsr223 post processor

```
def messageText = vars.get("messageTextVariable")
log.info("messageTextVariable: " + vars.get("messageTextVariable"))
```

Then i have an If token expire controller
${__jexl3((${__time(,)} - ${tokenGenerationTime}) > 6300000 ,)}
the call the get token

then in my case becuause i am pulling from a queue, i check no claims then i stop all thread
${__jexl3(${queueSize} == 0,)}

[image]